# How do I replace nftables rules atomically?

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, nftables

I'm trying to atomically replace nftables rules. Nftables's official wiki [states](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Atomic_rule_replacement) that -f is the recommended way to achive this. However, when I run `nft -f /path/to/new/rules` on Debian Buster, the new rules get added to the current rules instead of replacing them, and I end up with a system enforcing both rule-sets simultaneously.

The same thing occurs when I try to reload configuration via `systemd`'s `nftables.service`.

How can I get `nft` to discard the current rule-set while also adding a new rule-set in a single atomic operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation done with `nft -f /path/to/new/rules` *is* atomic: that means it's either done completely or not done at all (ie: reverted), and will affect all at once the next packet hitting the rules only once committed. It won't end (because of an error) only half-done. So if you don't delete the previous ruleset before, it behaves as expected: it atomically adds rules *once more*, as described in the notes of [Atomic rule replacement](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Atomic_rule_replacement) in the wiki:

> Duplicate Rules: If you prepend the `flush table filter` line at the
> very beginning of the *filter-table* file, you achieve atomic rule-set
> replacement equivalent to what iptables-restore provides. The kernel
> handles the rule commands in the file in one single transaction, so
> basically the flushing and the load of the new rules happens in one
> single shot. **If you choose not to flush your tables then you will see
> duplicate rules for each time you reloaded the config.**

For this you must, in the same transaction *delete* older rules before adding again your ruleset. The easiest (but affecting all of *nftables*, including *iptables-nft* if also used) is simply, similarly to what is described above, to prepend your ruleset `/path/to/new/rules` with:

```
flush ruleset
```

---

If you're loading different tables at different times to keep logical features separated (in *nftables*, a table can include any type of base chain (for the given family), it's not the direct equivalent of a table in *iptables* which has a fixed set of possible chain) it becomes a bit more complex because `flush ruleset` in one rule file would delete other tables (including *iptables-nft* rules if used along *nftables*). Then this should be done at the table level with for example (but read further before doing):

```
delete table inet foo
```

followed by the redefinition of it (`table inet foo {` ...). As-is, this creates an other chicken-and-egg problem: the first time this file would be read, eg at boot, the delete operation would fail, and thus everything would atomically fail as a whole because the table didn't exist. As declaring an already declared table's name is considered a no-op and thus won't fail, in the end this can be done:

```
table inet foo
delete table inet foo

table inet foo {
[...]
```

- note 1: For this to work properly in all cases [kernel >= 3.18 is required](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_tables#Deleting_tables), else better stick to `flush ruleset`.
- note 2: the wiki's note above suggests using for this case `flush table inet foo` but this should probably be avoided, because if sets are present this [won't delete element in sets](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_tables#Flushing_tables), leading again to adding instead of replacing elements if the elements are added by the ruleset and were changed there. It won't either allow to redefine the type/hook of a base chain. Using `table inet foo` + `delete table inet foo` doesn't have these drawbacks. Of course if one needs to keep elements in sets when reloading rules, one might ponder using `flush table inet foo` and adapt to the limitations of this method.

---

In all cases you should be careful when using `nft list {ruleset, table inet foo, ...} > /path/to/new/rules` to dump the current rules to a rule file: it won't include any flush or delete command, and you'll have to add them back manually. You can probably use [`include`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Scripting#Including_files) to overcome this by keeping your "plumber" statements outside of the actual rules.